# "zsh: file name too long:" when trying to run eval command

Tags: linux, terminal, command-line-interface, eval

I am trying run some integration tests on my linux. As part of the setup we spawn the service on a local server and run the integration test against that. Before running the integration test we execute the below command :
`eval $(aws ecr get-login-password --region us-west-2)`

When I am executing the above command I am getting the below error :

```
zsh: file name too long: 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
```

I am not able understand how to root bcause this issue because `eval` command doesn't really try to create a file, not sure what is going on here.
I was able to execute the above command properly but suddenly started to get the above error.

Comment: Why are you using `eval`? The `aws` command doesn't return a shell command, it just returns the password. I think you meant to use `echo`.

Comment: If the password contains any `>` or `<`, the part after that will be treated as a filename to redirect to/from.

Answer (score 0):

try

`ecr_login=$(aws ecr get-login-password --region us-west-2) && eval "$ecr_login"`

doing this means you're assigning the output to the variable `ecr_login` storing the content into the variable instead of executing the output directly.
it should avoid the 'file name too long' error.